# Continuously monitoring tasks in Android

Tags: android, android-service

How to continuously monitor particular event (those don't have broadcast receivers), say sensor changes, in Android. Is it better thing to start a Thread that runs infinitely in onStartCommand() of a background service?  Do we have any other options to do this more gracefully?

Thanks in advance,
JK

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you can provide some more details about what you actually need to monitor.

Sensors do have their call backs. (Almost all of them have it)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

And if you have any specific task which needs to be updated at regular interval, Create a simple **Service** and use **TimerTask** to check on regular interval.

Make sure you stop the service as soon as your task is done. (If no longer required)

Here is on useful blog for such things:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks--mobile-5788